# How to get all elements before and after the defined one in Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, python, arrays, arraylist

What is the equvalent of Pyhton arr[1:] in Java and C#, like how to get all elements before and after the defined one?
for example in Python I have

```
input:
arr=[1,6,7,9]
print(arr[1:])
output:
6,7,9
```

**WITHOUT FOR, WHILE, IF**
**preferably for ArrayList**

Comment: The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) is where you want to *start*.

Comment: The [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043173/how-to-get-all-elements-before-and-after-the-defined-one-in-java-and-c-sharp)'s where I want to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java:-

1 - create a list and add elements.

2 - use subList(start_index, end index) method.

**// Internally its use for loop to create a new copy of arraylist with defined index. but its faster as there are many system methods involved in this process. which work on os level**

3 - store result in list and print it.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    a.add(3);
    a.add(4);
    a.add(5);
    a.add(6);
    System.out.println(a);
    List<Integer> b = a.subList(1, a.size());
    System.out.println(b);
```

In C# -

1 - use array.skip(no of element you want to skip).

2 - store output in array.

C# is not my primary language so if there is anything wrong please comment I will correct it.

Comment: Not aware about python. but wrote my answer based on given input and expected output. can you clear me that what is arr[:1]. may be i need to change my answer according to that.

Comment: it is an index, as it is in braces []

Comment: This code will run as expected. If its helped. please acceptd answer with upvote.

Comment: i surely will when i have enough reputation) thanx

Answer (score 3):

### In C-sharp:

Use Linq methods to take the first n elements or skip the first n elements.

```
firstArray  = array.Take(14).ToArray(); // take only the first 14 elements
secondArray = array.Skip(2).ToArray();  // skip the first two elements
```

You could also combine those Linq commands like this:

```
Array  = array.Skip(4).Take(10).ToArray(); // takes the subarray from 4-14
```

### In Java:

Use Stream methods like in https://www.boraji.com/java-8-stream-limit-and-skip-methods-example

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(1, 2, 3, 4);
numbers.stream().limit(3).forEach(nn -> {
    System.out.println(n);
});
numbers.stream().skip(2).forEach(nn -> {
    System.out.println(n);
});
```

Or alternatively:

```
List<String> arrlist = arrlist.subList(2, arrlist.size()); // index from to
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method:

`int[] cut(int[] a, int start, int end);`

which accepts array `a`, `start` and `end` indexes, and returns copy of array `a` from `start` to `end` indexes.

Alternative for Python `arr[1:]` in Java may be `cut(arr, 1, arr.length);`

Answer (score -1):

In Java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("c");
        list.add("d");

        List<String> sublist = list.subList(list.indexOf("b"), list.size());
        System.out.println(sublist);
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58043422/5221149) given 14 minutes earlier, and doesn't even fit the question, since question is by index position, not by value.